# Compare two columns in two databases to insert the content of a third column into a forth one

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in  different databases:

#### b.dbo.table1

```
ID
Code
```

#### w.dbo.table2:

```
ID 
Code2 
ID2
```

I am in need of code that helps me to compare (`Code`) in `table1` with (`Code2`) in `table2`. If they are the same then insert (`ID`) from `table1` into (`ID2`) in `table2`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what's the link between your 2 tables.

If the link between your tables is through `Code` and `Code2`:

```
UPDATE T2 SET
    ID2 = T1.ID
FROM
    b.dbo.table1 AS T1
    INNER JOIN w.dbo.table2 AS T2 ON T1.Code = T2.Code2
```

If the link is through `ID` and the comparison by `Code`:

```
UPDATE T2 SET
    ID2 = T1.ID
FROM
    b.dbo.table1 AS T1
    INNER JOIN w.dbo.table2 AS T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE
    T1.Code = T2.Code2
```

I'm assuming that you meant an `UPDATE` of the column `ID2` when the codes match and *not* creating a new row just with the `ID2` value (which would require an `INSERT` operation).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
INSERT INTO w.dbo.table2 (ID2)
SELECT T1.ID
FROM b.dbo.table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN w.dbo.table2 AS T2
    ON T1.Code = T2.Code2
```

Here's the breakdown:

> I am in need to a code that helps me to compare (Code) in table1 with
>   (Code2) in table2

You can do this by joining the tables together. There are other methods that also exist, such as subqueries, where clauses, and others. I'm keeping it simple with a join to start as that is where you will typically see people perform this operation. As you progress in SQL development, you'll learn other tricks and tools. It's at this point when you begin to measure the results of the ways you do things, how much faster was it, how many resources did it use, was it optimally using indexes, etc. For now though, basic syntax and vanilla practice.

We are `SELECT`ing the ID column from `T1`. `T1` is the `ALIAS` I have given `b.dbo.table1`. The `INNER JOIN` is matching the values from `T1` and `T2` (`T2` is the `ALIAS` I gave `w.dbo.table2`) and when it finds a match between them, it will return the result set specified in the `SELECT` clause. The `ON` piece is where we are stating the `Code` column in `T1` must match exactly on `T2` in the `Code2` column.

> and if they are the same then insert (ID) from teable1 into (ID2) in
>   table 2.

The last piece I'll cover is the `INSERT`. I'm putting it ahead of the other query and telling it I want to `INSERT` into w.dbo.table2, specifically in the `ID2` column. This is matched to the `SELECT` of the query below. (Which is bringing the ID from T1 where code from T1 matches code2 from T2.)

[Jeremy Kadlec has a good MSSQLTips post on Inserts.](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2514/sql-server-insert-command-tutorial/)

[He also has one on joins.](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1667/sql-server-join-example/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help but for some reason it's generating repetitions. I tried to change it several times but the result is the same.

Comment: @Ibrahim Try adding a `DISTINCT` to your `SELECT` statement. If that does not help you, can you provide a table creation statement, some data insert statements, and the expected output? I would be able to see more clearly with a well defined example set and could give you a correct answer without guessing.